# Angular, dynamic param on lazy loaded route not working

Tags: angular8

I have an Angular 8 App that has lazyloading working on all the pages, except for 2 that have dynamic parameters where something is not working correctly

From the app routing module

```
  {
    path: 'product',
    loadChildren: './marketing/page/product/product-page.module#ProductPageModule'
  },
```

From the ProductPageRoutingModule

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: AppMarketingPageProductComponent,
    children: [
      { path: ':slug', component: AppMarketingPageProductComponent },
      { path: ':slug', component: AppMarketingPageProductComponent },
      { path: ':slug/:secondary', component: AppMarketingPageProductComponent },
    ]
  }
];
```

Routes are being put into the imports correctly, and the ProductRoutingModule is imported into ProductPageModule.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class ProductRoutingModule {}
```

In the AppMarketingPageProductComponent constructor

```
constructor(  private route: ActivatedRoute ) {}
```

With these 2 I try to get the params within onNgInit function

```
    this.route.params.subscribe( (params: Params) => {
      console.log(params);
    });
```

When I try to load the page I get an empty object. instead of "slug" or "slug" and "secondary" values key-value pairs.

Comment: i am also facing same issue in my current project.

Comment: check out the answer below, that's how I fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that what I thought were child routes aren't really child routes so this

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: AppMarketingPageProductComponent,
    children: [
      { path: ':slug', component: AppMarketingPageProductComponent },
      { path: ':slug', component: AppMarketingPageProductComponent },
      { path: ':slug/:secondary', component: AppMarketingPageProductComponent },
    ]
  }
];
```

needed to be changed to this

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: ':slug', component: AppMarketingPageProductComponent },
  { path: ':slug', component: AppMarketingPageProductComponent },
  { path: ':slug/:secondary', component: AppMarketingPageProductComponent },
];
```

now it works.